# Using html partials with webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm quite new in JS and webpack and I'm trying on my project to use partials for header and footer in order to not repeat them everywhere.

My first approach was to install `html-loader` and use in my index.html :

```
<%= require('html-loader!./assets/html/header.html') %>
```

It was working, only if I don't add any rule for html file in webpack config (I guess if I do it, it interfers with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`), however, my page is rendering :

```
[object Module]
```

and I don't find any good explanation on the web (related to a html file case).

Am I having a good approach, or there is another easier way to do it? I'm going to include these partials everywhere, but I don't exclude to create partials for things that I want to use in specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

the easier way is to use the html-bundler-webpack-plugin. This plugin supports many templating engines (Eta, EJS, Handlebars, Nunjucks, LiquidJS) "out of the box". The default template engine is fastest Eta (EJS like).

The simple usage, clean syntax, e.g., *./src/views/index.html*

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- specify a source style file, relative to html file -->
    <link href="../scss/styles.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- specify a source script file, relative to html file -->
    <script src="../js/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- specify a source partial file, relative to project path -->
    <%~ include('/src/views/header.html') %>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- specify a source image file, relative to html file -->
    <img src="../images/picture.png" />
    <!-- specify a source partial file, relative to project path -->
    <%~ include('/src/views/footer.html') %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The minimal Webpack config:

```js
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        // define templates here
        index: './src/views/index.html', // => dist/index.html
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|webp|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Note**
The entry point is a HTML file. All source script and style files should be specified directly in HTML.
The plugin resolves all source files in the HTML template and replaces the references with their output filenames in the generated HTML.

No additional plugins and loader required.

Comment: In my case, index is not a template, however header & footer are (or I have a wrong definition of template in mind). So does it mean I need to map on webpack.config.js all the different pages that exists on my website? (as these elements will be used everywhere)

Comment: Also, this seems not working with HtmlWebpackPlugin at the same time. However, it's what I use to create the index, import the right js files etc...

Comment: can you please create a small repo on github with simple pages, partials (header, footer), js, (s)css, images, fonts etc., then I can help you to create working solution.

Comment: I was going to do it then I tried something that I seen on internet, and it seems that the first attempt with html-loader is now working. I was just missing `.default` after. However, now I need to figure out how to have my header.html file using header.js, because it was a chunk for `index.html`